# What is the query to check if an attribute in a table existed or not?

Tags: sqlite

The question is in the title is clear, I guess.

What/how is the query to check if an attribute in a table existed or not?

I am doing with SQLite.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interrogate the database with `PRAGMA table_info(tablename);`. That will return the list of column names, their type, nullable or not, and default value.

Comment: Hi,

Yes, this could be a solution but indirectly of checking the table structure. Would it be a direct solution? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What other attributes do you mean? Like what is the primary key?

Comment: I meant an attribute (column name) of a table.

For example: Table A has 3 columns (fields)
- ID -> big int
- Name -> varchar
- DOB -> varchar

How can I check if the field (column) DOB is existed or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PRAGMA table_info` will return the list of columns, so you can go through them to see if your DOB column is present or not. You can't exactly query SQLite to see if a field exists or not, you have to make that own function yourself in whatever language/platform you use to call SQLite.